# Fetch a remote zip file and list the files within

Tags: python, google-app-engine, zip

I'm working on a small Google App Engine project in which I need to fetch a remote zip file from a URL and then list the files contained in the zip archive.

I'm using the `zipfile` module.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
# fetch the zip file from its remote URL
result = urlfetch.fetch(zip_url)

# store the contents in a stream
file_stream = StringIO.StringIO(result.content)

# create the ZipFile object
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(file_stream, 'w')

# read the files by name
archive_files = zip_file.namelist()
```

Unfortunately the `archive_files` list is always of length 0.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are opening the file with `w` permissions, which truncates it.  Change it to `r` permissions for reading:

```
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(file_stream, 'r')
```

Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects

Answer (score 1):

You're opening the `ZipFile` for writing. Try reading instead.